# PHP 5.5.23 MAMP php.ini missing open_ssl extension

Tags: php, openssl, mamp, php-ini

Im trying to use PHPMailer to send emails but i dosent work.
everyone is saying "uncomment extension=php_openssl" in the php.ini file but when i search for the openssl extension i cant find it. It's missing in my php.ini .

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

> "*...in the php.ini file but when i search for the openssl extension i cant find it*"

1. Open the php.ini and add:

   extension=php_openssl
2. restart apache